# Инсталятор программ на Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, install

Мне нужно сделал инсталято чтобы установить приложения на  C# Windows Forms котор просто добавляет программу в поиск и делает возможность открывать файлы .d этой программой. И пез коментарий безопасности скачать с сайта.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package Оно?

Answer (score 1):

Что касается инсталлера:

1. Открываем свойства проекта(того что с формами)
2. Раздел publish(хз как в руской версии)
3. Настраиваем
4. Жмакаем кнопку Publish
5. Done

Это и есть создание инсталлера. По другим вопросам создавай отдельные вопросы, а не все кидай в кучу.

Еще желательно прикрутить и цифровую подпись, но вряд ли в твоем случае она нужна.